# How to set cell left aligned in custom CollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have setup my collection view in a way, that my first image comes full size to the right and half the size of screen vertically with the following code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: ( self.collectionView.frame.height / 2 ))
        }
        let width = self.collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 1
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
```

[image]

it works ok. But when collection view has only 2 item then the second item comes in the middle rather that on the left.

How to fix this ??

Comment: You can add your content in UIView at center and put a UIView inside a cell contentview

Comment: sorry i am having hard time understanding what u are trying to say. can u post some example code?

Comment: @Mahabub Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @JuanCurti question updated

Comment: @Mahabub Just to know, why are you using collectionView instead of tableview?

Comment: client requirement